# Why do my similarity values change after each running with pretrained embedding word vectors and fix word tuples?

Tags: python, word2vec

**What do I want to do:**
I want to get similarity values out of word2vec for a lot of word tuples.
`Tuple_list_example = [('guard', 'suffrage'), ('guard', protest), ('guard', 'sea'), ('guard', 'demonstrations'), ('guard', 'definition')…]`
I imported the pretrained vectors of the Text8Corpus with genism
`w2v_model = Word2Vec(Text8Corpus(r'C:\\path’), size=100, window=5, min_count=150, workers=4)`

Everything works pretty well, except that I don't understand why the similarity values change each time after I run my code. I always take the same pre trained vectors and the same word tuples. 
Example:
Output after first hit: [-0.3895531, -0.3782139, -0.36835572, -0.36330146, …]
Output after second hit: [-0.40356663, -0.3905962, -0.37609994, -0.3635677,…]

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The word2vec algorithm inherently uses randomization as part of its training process: both in the initialization of vectors pre-training, and the progress of training.

Further doing a multi-threaded training means that slight variations in the OS-level scheduling of worker threads mean that even with the same training data, it won't be presented to the model in exactly the same order between runs, changing the final model state.

Further, Python itself slightly randomizes the behavior of `dict`s on each launch, to prevent certain kinds of denial-of-service attacks, which may in some versions affect the order in which discovered words are enumerated from run-to-run.

So, you should not expect identical results from subsequent runs, unless you've taken extreme steps to prevent all such variance (which is a bad idea for other reasons, including making training much slower & creating a false illusion of stability from an algorithm that at its core is not exact).

There's a bit more discussion in [Q11 & Q12 of the gensim FAQ](https://github.com/RARE-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism).

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot.